# Find three indices x, y, z such that M[x] + M[y] = N[z]

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given Two Array (Not Sorted) M and N. I have to find three index x, y (in M) and z (in N) such that M[x] + M[y] = N[z].
My initial algorithm takes O(m *m *n) solution. Please note, I have to find the indexes and sorting will change the indexes.

O(m *m *n) pseudo code (where m and n are length of respective array):

```
for(int i = 0; i < m - 1; i++)
    for(int j = i + 1; j < m; j++)
        for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            if(M[i] + M[j] == N[k] {
                print i, j, k
            }
```

I'm looking for more optimized solution.

Thanks.

Comment: have a google search about `k-SAT` problem. specifically, you are solving `2-SAT` problem, which is in P. optimization key word: meet-in-the-middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert `M` into hash array (hash set / hash table) so you will have `O(1)` contains check. Then iterate over all items in `N` and inside this loop iterate over your hash set, pseudocode:

```
foreach(integer x in N)
   foreach(integer setY in hashArray)
      if ( hashArray.Contains( x - setY ) )
         then your solution is: setY + (x-setY) = x;
```

You can find these items indexes in linear time. Overall running time is `O(|N|*|M|)`. Keep in mind that you might need to handle corner cases (like x = 2*setY).

Comment: Using Hash will tell me only element exist or not. I have to find the indexes. Finding indexes will have added complexity.

Comment: sure, but it wont change running time (in terms of asymptotics - big-O), save solution, break all loops and go for a linear scan in orginal array. Approximate running time is given by f(n, m) = n*m + n + m, f = O(n*m)